# Is there a way to call an API asynchronously multiple times but process the API one by one without delay in UI in .NET Core

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to hit an API multiple times in an asynchronous manner, but the tasks that is in queue due to asynchronous method must be processed one by one in .NET Core.

For example: I send an API call to insert 15 items of data into the database with for loop by using `httpclient.PostAsync`. Thus 15 async tasks are created.

However during my insert to the database the data should be such that each information should have been posted in the database at certain time interval in background but ui is not blocked during this process  and can be used for performing other operation?

Comment: If the UI has used `httpclient.PostAsync`, why would it care what the returned Task does on the other end? It does not block the UI regardless. Unless you `Wait()` on the task or similar, in which case it will block the UI no matter how asynchronously you are inserting in the database.

Comment: Why don't you POST the array of items instead? Why make 15 calls, when you can make 1 and let the API handle all the logic.

Comment: @GSerg How is it possible to not block the UI and insert 15 different data to database at the delay of lets say 5 second in the background such that insertion to db works in background and if i select from the db after 10 sec i should see only 3 data inserted and so on..??

Answer (score 0):

Pursuant to my comment, you can do this:

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<bool?>> UpdateObjects([FromBody] IEnumerable<yourObject> objects)
```

Just as easily as:

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<bool?>> UpdateObject([FromBody] yourObject object)
```

A single call would not block your UI and your user could happily go about their business while your API processes the entire request.